# Docker Image Protection

Tags: linux, docker

I have created one simple docker image of python code and it's working fine.
But I can able to copy the content of the file from docker to local machine is there any way to stop this and also how to secure docker image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protecting docker filesystem access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687121/protecting-docker-filesystem-access)

Comment: What is the threat you're concerned about?

Comment: I don't want to reveal my source code to the user

Answer (score 0):

So to protect the Docker image created for the Python Project I converted .py file to .pyd for windows and .so file for linux. Which makes it difficult to reverse engineering on the source code. User can export the project files but can not see the actual code.